# Replace contents of one column in txt file by custom strings

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I'm trying to replace the contents of the third column in my txt file below by customized text, i.e. instead of `GCM` in the third column below. I'd like to have customized text like `Example1`, `Example2`, ... , `ExampleN`. These replacement strings will come from another text file.

```
odu-encryption-2/1/5/odu4-1             enabled            GCM                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/6/odu4-1             enabled            GCM                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/7/odu4-1             enabled            GCM                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/3/1/odu4-1/odu2e-1     enabled            GCM                ^M^M
```

The file is delimited with spaces. In the last column, `^M^M` is just the standard output of router.

Desired output -

```
odu-encryption-2/1/5/odu4-1             enabled            John1                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/6/odu4-1             enabled            Mike2                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/7/odu4-1             enabled            Tom33                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/3/1/odu4-1/odu2e-1     enabled            WolfN               ^M^M
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Bash? I tried using `sed '3s/$/ Ccustom text/' testing.txt` to see if i can replace the 3rd row with a custom text but it replaces the existing text thats in there.

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details: (1) Where do the replacement strings come from - a different file, console input, stdout of a different process ...? (2) How is the file delimited? Tabs, spaces, or a combination thereof? (3) What do the `^M^M` mean? Is it a file format with non-Unix line endings? Do they still form their own column? (4) What did you already try, and where did you face problems?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but please don't add them as comments. Instead, edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators. Concerning your input method - it will be difficult to devise method to accept input from both sources; it might be best to restrict the problem to one of them.

Comment: Yes, please edit the question to add exra info. Also, if the strings are in a different file, what would the format be? How would we read it? How would we know which string to add to which line?

Comment: The format of the input file is standard txt file containing random strings as mentioned in the question above.

Comment: @rmb it isn't mentioned in the question. So the file is what, one string per line? Can the strings contain spaces? Should we use them sequentially so the string from line X will be added to lineX of the other file? In a specific order? Randomly? Also, you don't really want to do it in bash, right? You are OK with solutions using other tools like sed or awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other file has one string per line, like this:

```
$ cat file2
John1
Mike2
Tom33
WolfN
```

and you want to add them in the order they are found, you can do this:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}; {$(NF-1)=a[FNR]; }1' file2 file1
odu-encryption-2/1/5/odu4-1 enabled John1 ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/6/odu4-1 enabled Mike2 ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/7/odu4-1 enabled Tom33 ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/3/1/odu4-1/odu2e-1 enabled WolfN ^M^M
```

But this will collapse consecutive whitespace. If that's a problem, you could do something like this instead:

```
$ cat file1 | perl -lape 'BEGIN{open($fh,"file2"); while(<$fh>){chomp; $a[$.]=$_}} s/$F[2]/$a[$.]/ ' 
odu-encryption-2/1/5/odu4-1             enabled            John1                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/6/odu4-1             enabled            Mike2                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/7/odu4-1             enabled            Tom33                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/3/1/odu4-1/odu2e-1     enabled            WolfN                ^M^M
```

Comment: The Second Solution overlaps the existing text
$ cat file1 | perl -lape 'BEGIN{open($fh,"file2"); while(<$fh>){chomp; $a[$.]=$_}} s/$F[2]/$a[$.]/ ' 
ctextcryption-2/1/5/odu4-1             enabled            John1                ^M^M
ctextcryptiocryption-2/1/6/odu4-1             enabled            Mike2                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/1/7/odu4-1             enabled            Tom33                ^M^M
odu-encryption-2/3/1/odu4-1/odu2e-1     enabled            WolfN                ^M^M

Comment: @rmb "overlaps"? Please edit your question and explain so we can use formating. Also, note that `^M` usually represent carriage returns (`\r`, windows line endings) and the presence of an actual `\r` in the text would cause the cursor to move back and you would see text overwriting itself. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Happy with both of the solutions. Thank You so much